# Structure database?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Creating a database that will be searchable using a company's name and then list all the public owners of the company with their phone numbers. And I was wondering how to structure it. I was thinking of making the company name and ID and then make a new table for every company which would then store the information of every stock owner there. But then I thought about what if the owner owned multiple stocks then they would have duplicates in other tables with other companies so that would take a long time to query.

Can anybody help me structure this database? It's my first time doing this.

Comment: I recommend you take a class, or read some books, on relational database design; anything by Codd is a good (theoretical) start, though most designs eventually need to look at some level of denormalization from an implementation/performance perspective, ymmv; or are you taking a class and this is your homework/lab assignment?

Comment: No this is my own little project. I have already finished the algorithm for getting the data and I've made a CVS file to hold it all now I just need to know how to structure it. Honestly, i have used databases before in CS50 but I don't remember as much. I just need a quick tip on how to structure it all before I create something slow and inneffiecnt

Comment: Take a look [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/stock_exchanges/index.htm) and [here](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/investment_banking/index.htm). Take a look around that site - things you already know and how they're modelled!

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* have "a new table for every company"!

Think about the "Entities" - Company, Owner, etc.  One table for all the Companies, etc.

Think about "relationships"

- A many:many relationship needs an extra table; hints on schema: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
- A 1:many needs an id in one table to link to the other.
- 1:1 relationships are *usually* not advised; instead it is *usually* better to combine the tables.